# Java int division confusing me

Tags: java, int, division, octal

I am doing very simple int division and I am getting odd results.

This code prints `2` as expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 200;
    int hundNum = i / 100;
    System.out.println(hundNum);
}
```

This code prints `1` as **not** expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0200;
    int hundNum = i / 100;
    System.out.println(hundNum);
}
```

What is going on here?

*(Windows XP Pro, Java 1.6 running in Eclipse 3.4.1)*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The value `0200` is an *octal* (base 8) constant. It is equal to 128 (decimal).

From [Section 3.10.1 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I haven't ran into this before.  I feel like an idiot.  Thanks!

Comment: I looked at your rep score and I though it must be something else!

Comment: This is one of the most irritating features of C-based languages. I have never seen someone use an octal constant on purpose, but I've seen it cause problems multiple times.

Comment: It is a case of Occam's razor.  It's usually the simplest solution.

Comment: The only time I ever use octal constants on purpose is in the C `mkdir()` function.

Answer (score 6):

The value 0200 is an octal, which is **128** in decimal.

For further information, see the literals section of the [Primitive Data Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Observed an interesting behavior here.

If I do an `Integer.parseInt("0200")`, I get `200` as o/p.

Howzzat ?!

Comment: Well check the API doc for parseInt. It says it all:

public static int parseInt(String s) ... 

Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer.The  characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that  the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to  indicate a negative value.

Comment: parseInt parses a string with radix 10. A call to Integer.decode parses 0200 to 128.