# Can I customize syntax highlighting in Eclipse to show octal literals differently?

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, octal

I think octal literals are Very Dangerous Things™, and I'd like them to be glaringly obvious whenever I read source codes.

There must be a way to do this in Eclipse, right?

---

So it looks like standard Eclipse cannot be configured to do this? A custom colorer is required?

Comment: I'd like to know this too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705645/java-int-division-confusing-me

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746031/how-can-i-create-a-custom-eclipse-syntax-highlighter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, currently you can only configure a color for all Numbers in Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring. May I suggest creating an enhancement request at the Eclipse Bugzilla at http://bugs.eclipse.org/ (correct project is imho JDT / text)?

Comment: @polygenelubricants if you do post an enhancement request, please put a link to it, here.