# converting a calendar object into a string in java with format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"

Tags: java, datetime

I'm converting a date stored in a calendar object in a string for a query in MySQL. I need the string in format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", i.e.: "2010-01-01 15:30:00".
I'm using a code like:

```
    Calendar TimeStop = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeStop.set(2010, 01, 01, 15, 30, 0);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String TimeStop_Str = sdf.format(TimeStop.getTime());
```

now, the string, instead of being "2010-**01**-01 15:30:00" like I would expect is "2010-**02**-01 15:30:00".
I have already checked on http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for possible errors in the parser formula (for example the capital MM for month or capital HH for hours) but it didn't worked.

I guess that there is some other field that I should set, or maybe there is another method... any idea?

Comment: The Java coding convention is to use lowercase first letter for variable names, e.g. `timeStop`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Calendar.JANUARY`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.JANUARY) is actually `0`, not `1`.

When you provide `01` for the month field in `set`, you're actually setting the month to February, which is why you get `02` when `SimpleDateFormat` renders it as `MM`.

When you use any of the `Calendar.get/set` methods, you must take extra precautions to make sure that you are aware of this discrepancy between the "natural" 1-based indexing, and the more "awkward" `Calendar`'s 0-based indexing. Any time you're getting/setting the month of a `Calendar`, there's always this potential to cause a serious bug.

This is just one of those really awkward design in [`Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) that leaves a lot to be desired. One of the better, more pleasant date/time API library available out there is [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), so if at all possible, you may consider a switch to that library instead.

#### API links

- [`Calendar.MONTH`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) - "Field number for `get` and `set` indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year [...] is `JANUARY` which is 0".
- [`Calendar.set(…, int month, …)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) - "`month` - the value used to set the `MONTH` calendar field. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January."

---

#### On octal literals

Also, note that `01` is actually an octal literal (i.e. [base 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)). You shouldn't make a habit of prepending `0` to integer literals ([§3.10.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1)), because they can cause subtle bugs/errors unless you're very careful.

For example, `int i = 09;` is an illegal Java code.

```
    System.out.println(010); // prints 8, not 10
```

#### See also

- [Can I customize syntax highlighting in Eclipse to show octal literals differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398208/can-i-customize-syntax-highlighting-in-eclipse-to-show-octal-literals-differently)
- [Octal number literals: when? why? ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569/octal-number-literals-when-why-ever)

Comment: Danke!
this means that the Calendar starts from "0", but the parser start from "1"... ok
Thank you also for the other comment

Comment: @andystrath: For month fields of `java.util.Calendar`, yes, it starts from `0`. That's why when you `set` the month to `1`, it's actually `February`, which is `02` in `MM` format.

Answer (score 3):

It's just that months start from `0` (not `1`)

That said, you should not convert to string in order to insert a date in the DB. You can either use the timestamp, or [`java.sql.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) together with [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: (regarding the DB stuff) +1 from me; I don't know the exact details, but this does sound like the more sensible thing to do.