# startsWith() method in Java returns true on an empty String. How?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does “abcd”.StartsWith(“”) return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true)

The following simple Java code just uses the `startsWith()` method.

```
package startwithdemo;

final public class Main
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("My String".startsWith("M"));
        System.out.println("My String".startsWith("My"));
        System.out.println("My String".startsWith(""));
    }
}
```

It displays `true` in all the cases. The first two cases are obvious but in the last case (with an empty String), it's returning `true`. How?

Comment: Please check this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872936/why-do-strings-start-with-a-in-java

Comment: No characters? Makes sense to me, all strings start with nothing, then add characters.

Comment: ...Because that's the defined behavior of the function? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because that's how the API was designed, [see the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29).

But more seriously, one analogy can be to look at sets. Let's imagine a string is a set of characters, then the empty string is the empty set. [In set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set), the empty set is always part of any set.

---

*Why is the empty set a subset of every set? (taken from [here](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.06/narayana1.html))*

> The set A is a subset of the set B if and only if every element of A
>   is also an element of B. If A is the empty set then A has no elements
>   and so all of its elements (there are none) belong to B no matter what
>   set B we are dealing with. That is, the empty set is a subset of every
>   set.
>
> Another way of understanding it is to look at intersections. The
>   intersection of two sets is a subset of each of the original sets. So
>   if {} is the empty set and A is any set then {} intersect A is {}
>   which means {} is a subset of A and {} is a subset of {}.
>
> You can prove it by contradiction. Let's say that you have the empty
>   set {} and a set A. Based on the definition, {} is a subset of A
>   unless there is some element in {} that is not in A. So if {} is not a
>   subset of A then there is an element in {}. But {} has no elements and
>   hence this is a contradiction, so the set {} must be a subset of A.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns: true if the character sequence represented by the argument is
>   a prefix of the character sequence represented by this string; false
>   otherwise. **Note also that true will be returned if the argument is an**
>   **empty string** or is equal to this String object as determined by the
>   equals(Object) method.

Answer (score 3):

It is true:

`("" + "My String")` obviously starts with `""`.

That's the same as saying `"My String"` starts with `""`

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(""+""+""+"string"=="string") // output is true;
```